# For Spring restoring force $F=-kx$ (negative) ok but why Torque $T=C θ$ is positive? Its also a restoring force!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conventions, spring

For Spring restoring force $F=-kx$ (negative) ok but why Torque $Τ=Cθ$ is positive? It's also a restoring force! Where $C$ is torsional spring constant.

Answer (score 2):

Not so!

For example in the context of a torsion pendulum if the "*deflection*" is $\theta$, a component of the angle in a particular direction then the restoring torque needs to be written as $$T=-C\theta$$ i.e. in the opposite direction.

As an example look at this [torsion pendulum derivation](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node139.html).

Comment: As you imply, it's all about context. If we're thinking about the torque we need to apply to twist the fibre then it's $T=c \theta$, but if we're thinking about the torque the fibre exerts on the bob attached to it, then it's $T=-c \theta$.